# Qt Signals Inbetween Objects Causes Lockup

Tags: qt5

I would very much appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction as I am a bit stuck.  I am trying to write a simple widget counter program where the push of a QPushButton (startButton) initiates a counter that increments by plus one every second and displays the counter value in a QTextBrowser (outputBox).  My first class main window contains the startButton and ouputBox.  I have a second class chronoClass that receives a signal from the start button slot, waits one second and then increments counter and sends value via signal back to mainwindow slot that displays countervalue, up until this point works fine. If I leave at this (corresponds to commenting out  emit countResume(); ) in code below) then I get a counter that increments and displays with a one second time lag after every button press.  Ideally I would like to send a signal, countResume(), back from main window display slot to the chronos class slot to iterate counting process, it does not work though. I have read through online documentation and examples and I can't get to bottom of it.

My attempted implementation is as follows:

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QPushButton>

class QTextBrowser;
class QPushButton;

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

    public slots:
        void countRead(int counter);
        void on_startButton_clicked();


    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        QTextBrowser *ui_outputBox;
        QPushButton *ui_startButton;

    signals:
        void countResume();
        void startbutton();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <unistd.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui_outputBox = findChild<QTextBrowser*>("outputBox");
    ui_startButton = findChild<QPushButton*>("startButton");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::countRead(int counter)
{
    ui_outputBox -> setText(QString::number(counter));

    emit countResume();
}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    emit startbutton();
}
```

chronoClass.h

```
#ifndef CHRONOCLASS_H
#define CHRONOCLASS_H
#include<QWidget>
#include<unistd.h>



class chronoClass : public QWidget
{

    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        chronoClass();
        int counter{0};
    public slots:
        void chronoCount();

    signals:
        void countChrInc(int counter);

};

#endif // CHRONO_CLASS_H
```

chronoClass.cpp

```
#include "chronoClass.h"

chronoClass::chronoClass()
{}

void chronoClass::chronoCount()
{
    sleep(1);

    counter++;
    emit countChrInc(counter);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "philTimer.h"
#include "chronoClass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    chronoClass c;

    QObject::connect(&w, &MainWindow::countResume,
                     &c, &chronoClass::chronoCount);
    QObject::connect(&c, &chronoClass::countChrInc,
                    &w, &MainWindow::countRead);
    QObject::connect(&w, &MainWindow::startbutton,
                   &c, &chronoClass::chronoCount);

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your signal problem comes from the `sleep(1)` function in the chrono class. It will wait 1s, run 1 Qt event loop the wait 1s again. All interaction with the GUI must happen between 2 sleep call, in other word : never.

Is there any particular reason to have your chrono class instead of a QTimer?

Because it becomes quite easy when using a QTimer. here is an example, only 3 files

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextBrowser>
#include <QPushButton>

// That will replace your chrono class
#include <QTimer>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
        ~MainWindow();

    public slots:
        void timeout(); // This is connected to the timer
        void on_startButton_clicked();


    private:
        Ui::MainWindow *ui;
        QTextBrowser *ui_outputBox;
        QPushButton *ui_startButton;


        QTimer timer; // The timer object

        int counter; // Hold your counter here

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    counter(0)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui_outputBox = findChild<QTextBrowser*>("outputBox");
    ui_startButton = findChild<QPushButton*>("startButton");

    timer.setInterval(1000); // 1000ms => 1s

    //That signal is emitted every interval of the timer
    connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MainWindow::timeout);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::timeout()
{
    counter++;
    ui_outputBox -> setText(QString::number(counter));
}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    counter = 0;

    ui_outputBox -> setText("0");

    timer.start();
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Anyway, try to avoid the sleep function, it's a pain when using frameworks like Qt because it prevent the main event loop from running. Try to find Timers class instead, every modern framework have something like that.

Hope this helps!